# Lebesgue Integration Proof

Tags: analysis

I have been trying to teach myself Lebesgue Integration and came across the following question in a textbook.

Let $g \subset [0,1]$ be bounded and measurable. Suppose that it satisifes the property $\int_{[0,1]} g \chi_{[0,c)}\, d\mu = 0$ for all $c \in [0,1]$. Show that $g=0$ a.e.

Comment: Why, does that answer not satisfactory?

Comment: Note that $$\int_p^q gd\mu=\int_0^p gd\mu-\int_0^q gd\mu=\int_0^1 g\chi_{[0,p)}d\mu-\int_0^1 g\chi_{[0,q)}d\mu=0-0=0$$

Comment: So ask your question

Comment: See my comment above where I have proved this